# Ruby on Rails style guidelines, parentheses around method parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style

The following ruby style guide (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) states the following:

- Omit parentheses around parameters for methods that are part of an internal DSL (e.g. Rake, Rails, RSpec), methods that have "keyword" status in Ruby (e.g. attr_reader, puts) and attribute access methods. Use parentheses around the arguments of all other method invocations.

I've experienced debate as to what is part of the Rails internal DSL. Can someone answer what methods are part of the Rails internal DSL? Does it include methods like `link_to` or `I18n.t`? And what methods are not part of the Rails internal DSL?

Answer (score 1):

The guide you referenced is arguably ambiguous about this. It does not define what "internal DSL" means. So how should you resolve this?

First off, I'd say that it is more important to be consistent than which answer you pick, in this case.

I'd say, let's find out if link_to "should" have parens (again, not saying there is one right answer). A more systematic study could be done, but I glanced at a few things:

- The Rails Guides do *not* use parens with *link_to*, at least not the sections I looked at (see, for example, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)
- I glanced a few projects from [thoughtbot](https://github.com/thoughtbot) and [pivotal](https://github.com/pivotal) on github. I randomly selected a Rails project from each and then searched that repository for *link_to*. The thoughtbot project was 100% without parens. The pivotal was 14 to 1 without parens.

So with this highly anecdotal "data," I'd say go with no parens. Maybe that means *link_to* is part of the "internal DSL." If so, then probably, at the very least, the built-in methods you use in a view (path/URL helpers, form helpers, etc.) should probably be consider to be so as well.

Answer (score 1):

A guideline I read, that I liked, suggested it's ok to omit parenthesis for methods if its simple or clear but to use it if the reader or compiler can not easily identify the parameters or grouping of parameters. Reason for omission is reduce clutter and enhance readability but not at the expense of loosing clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that style guides are purely opinion, for example, for the `link_to` method you mention, I think it is cleaner to include the parenthesis but that is purely my opinion. The Rails DSL is pretty extensive and does include the methods you mentioned. You can check out the [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) to get the full list.